# Adding tags to posts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, post, tags, blogs

I am creating a blog in Rails using Scaffolding. I want to add a 'tags' field on each post like on StackOverflow and WordPress. I can do this with the string type ( `rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text tags:string` ) and then comma separated, but it's not good practice since I want the reader to browse by tags ( e.g. `/tags/web20` or `/tags/lol` ). How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have to make something like 
scaffold tag tagname:string

Each post can have several tags and each tag can have several posts. I haven't done this yet but I am interessted in doing this too!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tagging is so common that implementations are a commodity. I believe ["acts as taggable on"](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) is usually the preferred way of implementing tags.

See other popular solutions [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging).

If you wish to implement it yourself, you could dive into the source code to find some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a Tag model and using `has_and_belongs_to_many` to assign tags to posts. I don't know if the scaffold feature will help you create a form for that, but it shouldn't be difficult to add it yourself. I also suggest using the formtastic plugin as it's much easier and nicer to create forms with it.

Answer (score 0):

Err, the usual way? Add Tag entity, add `has_many :tags` in your Post entity. Then migrate. That would be all.

Comment: I did that and migrated. I'm fairly new to has_many and belongs_to. Could you also explain me how I can implement this in my controller and view? Thanks!