# Ruby on rails tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding tags to posts in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050133/adding-tags-to-posts-in-ruby-on-rails)

I have a simple yet tricky (for me at least) question... what would be the best way to create tags in my sample application blog?
I am adding tags using act-as-taggable, but can I make them clickable so that when people click on it, all posts with that tag would be shown?
I can't quite get it O___o

Any help is super appreciated!

Here is what i did so far:

in my posts controller

```
def tagged
  @posts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
  @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)
  @tagged_posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tags])  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @posts }
  end
end
```

then in my posts/show view

```
<% unless @post.tags.empty? %>
<div class="category">Category: 
<% @post.tags.each do |t| %>
    <%= link_to t.name, {:tag => t.name, :action => "tagged", :controller => 'posts'} %>
<% end %>
```

in my posts/tagged view

```
<% @tagged_posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="entry">
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <div class="content"><%= sanitize blog_truncate(post.content, :words => 100),:tags =>  %w(strong, b, a) %><br /><%= link_to "[read more]", post %>
      </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I kind of loosely followed this guide:
http://g-p.si/posts/tagging-with-acts-as-taggable-on

my issue is that the tag is clickable on my posts/show page, I get redirected to my tagged page and the url looks like mysite/tagged?tag=ruby
But my tagged page is blank...

Comment: with acts-as-taggable-on you can do https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/#finding-tagged-objects then you would just need a controller to pick that up (proper solution to be posted soon)

Comment: Common question, it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2050133/422353

Comment: mmh ye that would involve manually creating the tags model and relationships, and doesnt look like it's impossible but... I feel i'm so close to a solution! :D

Answer (score 1):

Each link for the tag that the user clicks on should have a href of something like:

```
/posts?tag=my_tag_name
```

And then in the posts controller

```
class PostsController
  def index
     if params[:tag].present? 
       @posts = Post.where(tag: params[:tag])
     else 
       @posts = Post.all
     end
  end
end
```

Note this code is not tested and I've never used acts as taggable so you should first make sure how to query for tagged posts.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost right, thanks for the hint! you have to use

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
```

instead of

```
@posts = Post.where(tag: params[:tag])
```

and it works like magic! :)